# Not able to compare username in database with that entered by the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

So I am trying to create a basic authentication app without using any modules or auth strategies. Just by pushing user credentials to a MongoDb database and then by comparing the entered credentials every time a user tries to login with the existing ones.

[text](https://github.com/DAObliterator/Basic_Auth.git)

For some reason i am not able to filter out the mongodb document with the same username entered by the user. When i try to log it to the console i am getting a query , i am expecting an object so that both the req.body.password and user.password can be compared.

Comment: What's the return value from `User.findOne`?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question; please do not just send us to some external repository platform.

Comment: @functorial  Its basically a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **User.findOne** function returns a Query object, which represents the pending query operation. To retrieve the actual user document, you need to execute the query using .exec().

You can modify your function in this way:

```
app.post("/api/v1/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
    .exec()
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(req.body.username);
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        const result = req.body.password === user.password;
        if (result) {
          res.redirect("/api/v1/dashboard");
        } else {
          res.status(404).json({ error: "entered password doesn't match" });
        }
      } else {
        res.redirect("/api/v1/register");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
    });
});
```

Let me know, If still the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's `findOne` returns a `Query`, which you need to execute to get a Promise containing the actual object. If you change the relevant lines to the following, you should be fine:

```
app.post("/api/v1/login", async (req, res) => {
  var user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).exec();
  ...
```